# GUI root in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, kubuntu, root

I'm using the newest Kubuntu, is there a way to have root privilages in the GUI? I don't like have to use the terminal, bacome root then use commands like cp, mv ,ln just to put something in a folder which requires being root to access. It would be much faster to just copy and paste files with the mouse.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are launching a gui app from the command line, you can use:

gksudo

edit: sorry, i misread your question.  To be able to use the file manager with the mouse, you need to use it with admin privileges.  Assuming you are using Konquerer (Kubuntu / KDE) as your desktop, check out this article for how to do this: http://humanreadable.nfshost.com/howtos/root_konqueror.htm